# How to loop over column in awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

When I do

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -A -I '/run/*' -I '/tmp/*' | cut -f2 -d"|" | \
awk '{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++){
    print $i
  }
}'
```

I get

```
/dev=0MB;6356;7151;0;7946
/dev/shm=74MB;6367;7163;0;7959
/sys/fs/cgroup=0MB;6367;7163;0;7959
/=12975MB;12792;14391;0;15990
/home=139507MB;190780;214627;0;238475
/mnt/dat0=2316MB;35376;39798;0;44221
```

**Question**

How can I loop over each element in `$i` separated by `;`?

Comment: If you could provide the output of your command could help on it then.

Comment: `loop over each element in $i`: What do you want to do after looping over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function `split()` with a regex set to `[;=]` to get each field into an array `a`.

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -A -I '/run/*' -I '/tmp/*' | awk -F'|' '{
  split($2, a, "[;=]");
  for(i in a){
      print a[i]
  }
}'
```

Note that the `cut` command can be replaced with `awk -F'|'` by using the 2nd field.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -A \
| cut -d'|' -f2- | xargs printf '%s\n' | sed 's/=/;/' \
| awk -F';' '{
    print "---"
    print "Path: " $1
    print "Size: " $2
    print "Warn: " $3
    print "Crit: " $4
    print "Min: " $5
    print "Max: " $6
    print "---"
}'
```

`cut -d'|' -f2-` selects the performance data.

`xargs printf '%s\n'` puts each entry on a separate line.

`sed 's/=/;/'` replaces the first `=` on each line with a `;` for convenience.

`awk -F';' …` splits each line at `;` and assigns the positional parameters as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the delimiter flag.  Use `awk -F ';'`.

Comment: The input to awk at this point is actually just the sample output but on a long line separated by spaces, because the original awk script is just a fancy way of saying `xargs printf '%s\n'`. Changing the delimiter doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
awk '1' RS=';' ORS='\n'
```

---

> After your command ...check_disk...| cut -f2 -d"|"
>   You get line like /dev=0MB;6356;7151;0;7946
>   The awk do nothing because the default FS (field separator) is space and there is no space in your lines.
>   If you tell awk that RS=';'
>   Each record end with ';'
>   For each line read, awk find more than 1 record.
>   If you tell awk that ORS (output field separator)="\n"
>   awk print each record in a new line
>   So with the previous line
>   awk '1' RS=';' ORS='\n'

you get :

> /dev=0MB
>   6356
>   7151
>   0
>   7946

This awk is very simple the 1 only tell awk print.

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: @user2722968 I add explain in the answer.